# Rails 6 & Bootstrap 5: Modal keeps open after History Back and cannot be closed

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, browser-history, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have discovered a strange behavior with modal windows and need help there.

If I open a modal window in which a link to another page exists, follow the link and then go back via browser history back, the modal window remains open and cannot be closed.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="/">Next Link to...</a>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the link points to an external page, it does not seem to happen. Maybe it has something to do with caching, but I don't know exactly where to start looking.

If it has something to do with the bfcache, how would I be able to solve such a problem and why does the Bootstrap JavaScript no longer work?

Comment: I do not believe Bootstrap modal windows are intended to jump to new pages.  But if you must you may need to close the open modal first and then postback to the new page.

Comment: @fnostro It don't jump to new page. It is still open when I redirect back via browser history back. Looks like caching or sth.

Comment: Then can you please clarify?  Because your tag `<a href="/">Next Link to...</a>` says otherwise.  This is indeed a "jump" to your root page. If that modal remains open or if it reappears when you "go back" then you have a leftover modal artifact for which the original JS has been obliterated.  In either case you need to manually close the modal before the postback occurs.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to [Trigger a Full Reload](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#ensuring-specific-pages-trigger-a-full-reload):

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta name="turbo-visit-control" content="reload">
</head>
```

In my case with Rails 7 & Turbo, I added a yield in my application layout

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.slim
= yield(:head)
```

In some views I added:

```
# view with modals
- content_for :head do
  meta name="turbo-visit-control" content="reload"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Jquery like this

```js
 $("#link").click(function(){

        $("#exampleModal").modal('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>
      
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <a href="/" id="link">Next Link to...</a>
            </div>
      
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```